# Css error display inline-table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-select

I'm trying to use a library bootstrap selector but i have an issue with the class input-group which contains "display inline-table". selected words go out of input field. I want to keep this class without modify "display inline-table"

I tried some display initial or block on children but its not working.

Without class "input-group"

[image: Without input-group class]

With class "input-group" but field grows

[image: With input-group class]

Thx for help.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="panel" id="liste_diffusion">
      <label> test </label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" multiple>
          <option>PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP</option>
          <option>CSS CSS CSS CSS CSS CSS CSS CSS CSS </option>
          <option>HTML HTML HTML HTML HTML HTML </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Hi, didnt see your answer, sorry. I tried to have the same result as picture 1  but with class input group. But input group trigger a field grow, no expected. Nandita Arora Sharma provide a good answer with dislay flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this style

```
.panel .input-group {
  display: flex;
}
.bootstrap-select {
   flex: 1;
}
```

```css
.panel .input-group {
  display: flex;
}
.bootstrap-select {
   flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="panel" id="liste_diffusion">
      <label> test </label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" multiple>
          <option>PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP</option>
          <option>CSS CSS CSS CSS CSS CSS CSS CSS CSS </option>
          <option>HTML HTML HTML HTML HTML HTML </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thx you for your fast answer. It works but the issue still there on responsive size screen even if I use percent. Do you have some other tips ? thx

Comment: what resolution is it causing the issue ? and can you plz show image of whats happening?

Comment: I added information for your answer with 70% percent. Thx you

Comment: Hi, this answer resolve issue. Thx a lot, have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

I add informations to resolve the problem :

what's happening with max width 70% :

```css
.bootstrap-select{
      max-width: 70%;
    }
```

**Without selected elements :**

[image: max width 70%]

**With selected elements field continues to grow :**

[image: max width 70%]

I cant use px for responsive size.